# Installing Mono on RedHat 7.1

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, mono-framework

Has anyone succeeded in installing Mono (the Linux .NET framework project) on the (outdated I know) RedHat 7.1 Linux distribution?

I need advice where to get started, I could find no resource on the web that would refer to RedHat and Mono together...

Thanks!

Comment: It was a PITA to get 2.6 on Ubuntu 9.10, but doable. Are you running into any specific problems?

Comment: It's *so* outdated that one of its successors is 5 releases ahead, and the other is just a couple shy...

Comment: @Frank Krueger, I don't know *where* to even start...

Comment: This is probably no help or consolation to you, but my Ubuntu 9.10 distribution contains Tomboy Notes so there's probably a mono underneath... it's there and I didn't have to do anything for it. Is "to hell with this, I ain't supporting this" an option for you?

Comment: Haha, yes it is, but it's highly desireable.

Comment: [7.1 (Seawolf) is from April 16, 2001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux#Version_history), more than a decade ago. I wonder if this question makes sense anymore.